# apache doesn't restart on vagrant

Tags: apache, vagrant, vagrantfile

I have a vagrant site setup on my machine as client-machine by vagrantfile (received it from client).

Now on on the machine, I'm unable to restart the apache server. I did the following commands.

- sudo service apache2 restart
- dpkg-reconfigure -plow apache2

both are giving me following error.

- Restarting web server apache2                                                                                                                [fail]
- The apache2 configtest failed.
  Output of config test was:
  apache2: Syntax error on line 219 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default.conf: No such file or directory
  Action 'configtest' failed.
  The Apache error log may have more information.
  invoke-rc.d: initscript apache2, action "restart" failed.

Also, when I try to access the error log, it's giving me permission issue.

please help me resolve this issue.

Thanks,
Dilip Gupta

Comment: you would need to paste the important piece of your apache2.conf file and indicate that the directory in error message exists and who is the owner of the folder and files

Comment: @FrédéricHenri, I believe you mean for this.

ls -la /etc/apache2/apache2.conf 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 7115 Jan  7  2014 /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

apache2.conf - https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Z3VPKVrKAmAdgc28XD-5jqpej5-Xrz4iYJcZal_H594/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Check `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` I think in 219 line apache try to get file from mounted folder and you don't have it on your computer.

Comment: @ArtemIlchenko, I checked the /etc/apache2/apache2.conf file, It's searching for deafult.conf file into /var/www (the mounted) folder. 

I do have the file in that specific mounted directory, but somehow, it's not reading it. I checked and saw the default.conf file has 644 permission. Is that has to be with different access permission?

please let me know. Thanks !

Comment: Try set 777 permitions